# Where should I place the ScrollView declaration within my XAML hierarchy? Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I defined a grid to place my views in but I need to scroll vertically to see them all. Where in my code should I add the ScrollView? Within the grid? Here's my current code. I'll also accept criticism on how to better construct this page too. I'm relatively a novice.

```
<ContentPage Title="Browse Providers">
    <Grid BackgroundColor="#689dff">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="20" Grid.RowSpan="4" Text="Browse Service Providers" 
    FontSize="28">
    </Label>
    <Button Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="10" Grid.RowSpan="4" Text="Videography" FontSize="20" 
    TextColor="Green">
    </Button>
    <Button Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="10" Grid.RowSpan="4" Text="Babysitting" FontSize="20" 
    TextColor="Green">
    </Button>
    <Button Grid.Row="11" Grid.Column="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="10" Grid.RowSpan="4" Text="Pet Sitting" FontSize="20" 
    TextColor="Green">
    </Button>
    <Button Grid.Row="14" Grid.Column="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="10" Grid.RowSpan="4" Text="Lawn Care" FontSize="20" 
    TextColor="Green">
    </Button>
    <Button Grid.Row="17" Grid.Column="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="10" Grid.RowSpan="4" Text="Appliance Repair" FontSize="20" 
    TextColor="Green">
    </Button>
    <Button Grid.Row="20" Grid.Column="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="10" Grid.RowSpan="4" Text="Graphic Design" FontSize="20" 
    TextColor="Green">
    </Button>
    <Button Grid.Row="23" Grid.Column="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="10" Grid.RowSpan="4" Text="Photography" FontSize="20" 
    TextColor="Green">
    </Button>
    <Button Grid.Row="26" Grid.Column="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="10" Grid.RowSpan="4" Text="Painting" FontSize="20" 
    TextColor="Green">
    </Button>
    <Button Grid.Row="29" Grid.Column="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="10" Grid.RowSpan="4" Text="Plumbing" FontSize="20" 
    TextColor="Green">
    </Button>
    <Button Grid.Row="32" Grid.Column="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="12" Grid.RowSpan="4" Text="House Cleaning" FontSize="20" 
    TextColor="Green">
    </Button>
</Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your `GridView` with `ScrollView`:

```
<ScrollView>
   <GridView />
</ScrollView/>
```

Few suggestions: 
1) Use [styles](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/), to define `TextColor` and `FontSize` only once.
2) If all of your `Rows` & `Columns` should have equal or similar size simplify the definition:

```
<ColumnDefinition />
<RowDefinition />
```

More about `Grid` layout can be found [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid/). 
3) Get familiar with "Xamarin.Forms Performance" [guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/deployment-testing/performance/). 
4) Use [XAMLC](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xamlc/) especially if you are new to Xamarin.Forms and XAML.

Good luck.